# javascript function not redirecting to the given link

Tags: javascript, json

In the JavaScript function below when I debug line by line using firebug 'windows.location' works perfectly and it will redirect to the given link. But when I run it without debugging it using firebug,even though the password and username is correct, the page redirection will not happen. Can any one explain me why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            var uname = $('#txtUserName').val();
            var Password = $('#txtPassword').val();
            if (uname != null && Password != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                  data: { type: "login", Uname: uname, Pword: Password,ran:Math.random() },
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url:"/CreatePdf.ashx",
                    success: function (result) {
                      if(result=='1')
                      {
                        window.location = "/home.aspx";
                      }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('spPassword').innerHTML = "Please Enter Username/Password";
            }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the code inside the deepest "if" get run? Is result=='1' true?

Comment: Add an `error` handler to your `.ajax` call and see if it's hitting that. Are you sure the request is getting sent? Are you sure a response is sent back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the success function is never called (because of problems with ajax), or the `result` argument is not the string `"1"`. We have no crystal balls to see what is happening, so you will have to debug it yourself:

```
$.ajax({
    …,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("result: ", result);
        if(result=='1')
             window.location = "/home.aspx";
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.log("Ajax failed with "+status+" due to "+error);
    }
);
```

Also use the network panel of your developer tools to check whether the server sent the expected response.